# How to copy gif into clipboard using javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas

I have implemented this solution:

```js
async function copyGif(index) {
     try {
        const thumbnail = thumbnailStore.thumbnails[index];
        const url = `https://sample.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/gifs/${thumbnail.gif_path}`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        await navigator.clipboard.write([
            new ClipboardItem({
                [blob.type]: blob
            })
        ]);

        setTimeout(() => {
            thumbnail.snippetCopied = false;
        }, 2000);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.name, error.message);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting error image/gif cannot be copied using the ClipboardItem. Is there a way we could copy gif to clipboard?

Comment: same problem for me, is resolved here?